# Angular - Exception when adding dynamic component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-changedetection

I have a simple test code for adding dynamic components with Angular 4.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'component',
  template: `

    <ul><li #item *ngFor="let number of list">{{number}}</li></ul>

    <ng-template #anchor> </ng-template>


    <ng-template #template>
      <li><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="myInput"/></li>
    </ng-template>`
})
class _Component {

  @ViewChild('template')
  template: TemplateRef<any>


  @ViewChild('anchor', { read: ViewContainerRef })
  anchor: TemplateRef<any>


  @ViewChildren('item', { read: ViewContainerRef })
  items: QueryList<ViewContainerRef>
  myInput='';
  list: number[] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.anchor.createEmbeddedView(this.template)
  }

}
```

All this code is doing is adding a dummy template at the end.

[image]

But this code throws an Exception :

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed
>   after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: ''.
>   It seems like the view has been created after its parent and its
>   children have been dirty checked. Has it been created in a change
>   detection hook ?

It is well descriptive exception. A view has been updated after already checked for changing.

But there are few things which I don't understand here :

**Question(s) :**

**1:**

If I remove the `input` from the template  - so now the template is :

```
<ng-template #template>
    <li></li>
</ng-template>
```

— Then I don't get an exception. Why is that ?

**2:**

Another solution(among many) is to replace `ngAfterViewInit` with `ngAfterContentInit`. I already know the difference between those two.

If so - can I conclude ( *from the fact that the exception is gone*) that at each Angualr's event - a change detection is occurred? (*which make sense becuase `ngAfterViewInit` happens _after_ `ngAfterContentInit`*) , so maybe Angular has detected the prev dynamic change  in `ngAfterViewInit` ? Am I right?

[**PLNKR**](https://plnkr.co/edit/swDUqgAiObrE805DmD3l)

Comment: why do you insert into `<ng-template #anchor`? did you intent to use `<ng-container`?

Comment: @Maximus It doesn't matter (IMHO). Angular adds dynamic content AS A SIBLING. so it really doesn't matter .

Comment: I recommend you read [Everything you need to know about change detection in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f) and also [this](https://hackernoon.com/angulars-digest-is-reborn-in-the-newer-version-of-angular-718a961ebd3e#d14a)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I remove the input from the template - so now the template is :

The input is not causing the problem. `ngModel` directive causes a problem. Directives and components instances are represented as view nodes inside angular - sort of children of the current component. During each change detection cycle, Angular updates inputs for these component/directive instances. Here is the excerpt from the [Everything you need to know about change detection in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f#c35d) that shows the order of operations:

> - updates **input** properties on a child component/directive instances (1)
> - calls **AfterContentInit** and AfterContentChecked lifecycle hooks on **child** component/directive instances (5)
> - **runs change detection for a child view** (repeats the steps in this list) (8)
> - calls **AfterViewInit** and AfterViewChecked lifecycle hooks on **child** component/directive instances (9)

So assume that Angular is doing change detection for the AppComponent. It runs change detection for the `_Component` (6). There are no directives yet so nothing to check. Then Angular calls `afterViewInit` hook for the `_Component`, where you create a child directive instance `ngModel`. But the change detection for the directive `ngModel` is never triggered! After the current change detection cycle is finished, Angular checks for changes and finds that `@Input` of `ngModel` is an empty string, but the previous values is `undefined` since it was never checked.

Compare that with the case when you used `AfterContentInit` hook. Angular calls that hook for `_Component`. You create a child directive there. Angular runs change detection for the `_Component`. Now, the directive already exists so change detection is also run for this child directive as part of change detection for the `_Component`. Since Angular applied empty string initial value, no error occurs next time the directive is checked.

Comment: Maximus -  thank you for your article. So Angular does not trigger  change detection at each event method - Only at phases 3,7,8 ? ( In other words - in what angular-events  - a change detection occurs?)

Comment: you probably have to read the entire article. all operations listed in the article are part of change detection for a particular view/component. you might have something different in mind when you say `change detection`, what do you mean by `change detection`?

Comment: Forget it :-). I will have to read it and if I'll have a question - I'll ping. (BTW - I did mention that I know the order difference of events - in my question.  , the thing which I didn't know is whether angular triggers  "change detection" at _each_ event.

Comment: @Royi, yeah, read the article and follow up :). It's pretty detailed, I've spent considerable amount of time to investigate and write it. By the way, finishing another article on dynamic components. Follow me on medium to get notified :)

Comment: Sure. :-). Thanks.

Comment: Regarding your reply about `ngModel` : Why do you say that  it updates a _parent_ to an empty string ? . The input is not inside a sub component. Does the input considered to be a _child_ of the component?

Comment: @Royi, I've updated the answer, see if makes sense now

Comment: BTW - the numbers in parenthesis are inconsistent with the ones that in the article. ( just saying - for future readers).

Comment: Hmm, I've tried to create an embeedded view in `ngAfterContentInit()` but I am still getting the exception ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50051077/icon-not-showing-when-creating-embedded-view)). Interestingly the demo which I am referring to does not have the issue I am having.