# Angular TemplateRef ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular

just playing around with TemplateRef

so I've set up this simple code

and in the chrome console I've got

**ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was cheched**

I can see the point if inside ng-template

would be a ngModel as in this post

[Angular - Exception when adding dynamic component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44241057/angular-exception-when-adding-dynamic-component)

but with simple binding .....

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <ng-template #myTemplate>
      <button class="tab-button"
                  (click)="login()">{{loginText}}</button>
      <button class="tab-button"
                  (click)="signUp()">{{signUpText}}</button>
    </ng-template>
  `
})
export class AppComponent  implements AfterViewInit, AfterContentInit {
  @ViewChild('myTemplate') tmpl: TemplateRef<any>;

  loginText = 'Login';
  signUpText = 'Sign Up';

  constructor(private view:ViewContainerRef){}

  login() {
    console.log('Login');
  }

  signUp() {
    console.log('Sign Up');
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
   this.view.createEmbeddedView(this.tmpl)
  }

  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    // It doesn't work either
    //this.view.createEmbeddedView(this.tmpl);
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What if you put the createEmbeddedView call inside of ngOnInit? That should probably work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `#myTemplate` is static view query you can use `ngOnInit` hook

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   this.view.createEmbeddedView(this.tmpl)
}
```

Comment: If it's not static, what should you do?

Comment: @MattTreichel You should wait till it is initialized. E.g. do it in `ngAfterViewInit`

Comment: But that's what causes `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`...

Comment: @MattTreichel try to wrap it in a Promise or you will have to call change detection explicitly