# Icon not showing when creating embedded view

Tags: angular, angular5

I am having this layout, inspired by [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/adv-ng-left-nav?file=app%2Fleft-nav.component.ts), which lets components decide how the header looks like:

```js
<div class="main" [@applicationTransition]="applicationState" fxLayout="column" fxFlexFill>

  <nav class="header" [@headerTransition]="applicationState">
    <ng-container #vcr></ng-container>
  </nav>

  <main class="content" fxLayout="column" fxFlex style="overflow: hidden; height: 100%">
    <router-outlet #o="outlet" fxLayout="column" fxFlex></router-outlet>
  </main>

</div>
```

However, it seems that using `<mat-icon>` does not work in this context - at least not completely. If I set an icon like the following:

```xml
<div *headerContent>
  <button mat-mini-fab [routerLink]="['/home']">
    <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
  </button>
</div>
```

the button icon is not displayed. It only says "*home*". I have to click the button in order to make the icon show up.

As far as I can tell I am doing the same as in [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/adv-ng-left-nav?file=app%2Fleft-nav.component.ts):

```js
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this
    .headerContentService
    .contents
    .subscribe(ref => {
      if (this.current !== null) {
        this.current.destroy();
        this.current = null;
      }
      if (ref === null) {
        return;
      }
      this.current = this.vcr.createEmbeddedView(ref);
    });
}
```

---

I also noticed that setting `[routerLink]="['/home']"` will throw me the following error:

```
ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined: undefined'. Current value: 'undefined: /home'. It seems like the view has been created after its parent and its children have been dirty checked. Has it been created in a change detection hook ?
    at viewDebugError (core.js:9817)
    at expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError (core.js:9795)
    at checkBindingNoChanges (core.js:9962)
    at checkNoChangesNodeInline (core.js:14010)
    ...
```

---

If I [change the example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/adv-ng-left-nav-xbjl5d?file=app/app.component.ts) s.t. I am having a `routerLink` for a `button` it is working. I'm not quite seeing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Note:** I do not know if this is the most elegant solution so if there is a better way to do this please provide an answer and I am going to accept it.

---

After reading "*[Everything you need to know about the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4)*" I figured that `setTimeout()` might solve the problem and indeed it did.

I simply modified the implementation of `ngAfterViewInit() to:

```js
ngAfterViewInit(): void {

  this
    .headerContentService
    .contents
    .subscribe(ref => {

      setTimeout(() => {

        if (this.current !== null) {
          this.current.destroy();
          this.current = null;
        }
        if (ref === null) {
          return;
        }
        this.current = this.vcr.createEmbeddedView(ref);
      });

    });
}
```